# 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' could not be resolved

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

> `Error    1   The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' could not be resolved`
>
> `k:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll   App2`

I got this error message after adding `system.windows.forms` reference.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System` (v4) in the same assembly that you added the `System.Windows.Forms` reference?

Comment: yes . I have 3 references.  .net , windows , windows.forms

Comment: What @roken is asking is whether you have a reference to `System.dll` since that is the assembly whose type is not being resolved.

Comment: What type of application is this, if it is a Winform application it should just work.

Comment: @AndySurya I'm not sure what ".net" refers to. Are you purposefully mixing WPF and WinForms? And that error says you do not have a reference to System, or at least not the proper version.

Comment: sorry , my bad. i tried to add `system.dll` but failed due `this component is already automatically referenced by build system `

Comment: @MarkHall i think its WPF since i used `xaml`

Comment: @AndySurya For WinForms on 4.5 you should probably have as a minimum: Microsoft.CSharp, System, System.Core, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms. If you aren't using WPF, you don't need System.Windows.

Comment: @AndySurya If you're exclusively using WPF, remove the reference to System.Windows.Forms

Comment: I removed the `.forms`. Still got an error cause I need to use `.forms.timer`. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Wpf I made quick working example.  Make sure your project references look like this.

[image]

**MainWindow**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tmr.Interval = 2000;
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
            tmr.Start();
        }

        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmr.Stop();
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

---

And as roken stated it would be easier if you could use the Wpf Dispatcher Timer. IN looking at the example link there is no pressing need to be using a Windows Form Timer, the Dispatcher timer will work fine in this case since this is a WPF program.

**Edit Modified based on your link**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmrStart = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmrStop = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmrStart.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2); //Delay before shown
        tmrStop.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);  //Delay after shown
        tmrStart.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        tmrStop.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrStop_Tick);

    }

    void tmrStop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrStop.Stop();
        label1.Content = "";
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrStart.Stop();
        label1.Content = "Success";
        tmrStop.Start();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tmrStart.Start();
    }


}
```

Comment: Why even use the winforms timer? Use DispatcherTimer for WPF.

Comment: @roken You are correct, I am just trying to answer the OP's question as asked.

Comment: @AndySurya The above code is working for me. Is there a reason why you are neeeding to use the Windows.Forms.Timer?

Comment: @MarkHall i want to make something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928532/using-a-timer-to-display-text-for-3-seconds)

Answer (score 3):

If you're exclusively using WPF, there's no reason to reference System.Windows.Forms (WinForms). These are two different technologies and I wouldn't recommend mixing them unless it's necessary.

If you're using the WinForms Timer, consider using WPF's [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) instead.

Comment: @AndySurya That namespace is in WindowsBase.dll (the MSDN docs tell you which assembly must be referenced).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the reference to `System` manually.

1) Right click on your project. Click on `Unload Project`.

2) Right click on the unloaded project. Click on `Edit <YourProjectName>.csproj`

3) Find the `ItemGroup` which contains all the `<Reference Include="AssemblyName">`s and add `<Reference Include="System" />` on a new line.

4) Save the file and right click on your project and click on `Reload Project`

Comment: ah well, that's unfortunate! You're not making a Metro app by any chance are you because `System.ComponentModel.Component` is not supported for Metro Apps. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithnativecode/thread/208117de-e65c-443b-86ab-6e7f935f16b9